# Passing value from one function to another C++

Tags: c++, function-declaration

I'm writing two functions: one of them is for "filling" array with random values and int the second function I have to use the same array, choose one row and find the min element of that row.

But the problem is that I don't know how to pass values from one function to another.

Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fillarray(int arr[5][5], int rows, int cols) {
    cout << "Static Array elements = \n\n" << flush;

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        cout << "Row " << i << "  ";
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            cout << arr[i][j] << " " << flush;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << " \n\n";
}

void minarray(int a, void fillarray) { // don't know what to write here

there:
    int min = INT_MAX; // Value of INT_MAX is 2147483648.

    if(a > 4) {
        cout << "Invalid input! " << endl;
        goto there;
    }

    for(int counter = 0; counter < 5; ++counter) {
        if(arr[a][counter] < min) min = arr[a][counter];
    }
    cout << "Minimum element is " << min << endl;
}
int main() {
    int z;

    srand(time(NULL));
    const int rows = 5;
    const int cols = 5;
    int arr[rows][cols];
    fillarray(arr, rows, cols);
    cout << "Enter the number of row: ";
    cin >> z;
    minarray(z, fillarray) 
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: `void fillarray` ? What do you want? Do you want to pass arr from main to `minarray()`

Comment: Note: You are missing a `;` after `minarray(z, fillarray)`. This can't compile.

Comment: `goto there;` ? Did you actually learn about `goto` as one of the first things?

Comment: In the scope of `minarray`, the function doesn't know what `arr` is. It can't just pluck `arr` from main, you need to explicitly send it the array, just like you sent `arr` to `fillarray`.

Comment: @drescherjm. Yes, What's the problem?

Comment: Do it the same way you did in `fillarray()` probably like this: `void minarray(int a,int arr[5][5], int rows, int cols)`

Comment: @TedLyngmo it wasn't me, they taught me at school.

Comment: @drescherjm I want to pass same array from fillarray to minarray.

Comment: Correct, the same way can and will work. You have the `arr` variable in `main()`. You can pass it the same way to minarray() as you did to fillarray

Comment: @jane Too bad. Forget that you know about `goto` for now. There's always™ a better solution.

Comment: @TedLyngmo then what can i do when user input some number that greater than the number of rows?

Comment: @jane I made a complementary answer to the other answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the function `fillarray` has redundant parameter `cols` because this number is known from the declaration of the first parameter `int arr[5][5]`.

Th function can be declared like

```
void fillarray(int arr[5][5], int rows )
```

You could supply the parameter `cols` in case when not the whole array is filled in the function.

You already filled the array by this call

```
fillarray ( arr, rows, cols );
```

The function performed its task. So there is no need to reference the function one more time as you are trying

```
minarray(z, fillarray)
```

The function `minarray` can be declared either like

```
void minarray( const int arr[], size_t n );
```

and called like

```
minarray( arr[z], cols );
```

with a preliminary check that z is less than 5.

Or it can be declared like

```
void minarray( const int arr[][5], size_t n, size_t row );
```

and called like

```
minarray( arr, rows, z );
```

Pay attention to that there is the standard algorithm `std::min_element` that allows to find minimum element in an array.  And to fill an array with values you can use the standard algorithm `std::generate`.

And each function should do only one task. For example the function `fillarray` should silently fill the array with values. To output the array you could write a separate function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this even compiles, but i'm guessing you want to pass int arr[x][y] from the fill Array function to the minArray function. To do that you first need to include arr as a parameter of minArray. From there you need to pass it by reference. Then, you can call minArray from fillArray.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is call fillarray to fill your array. So it would look like

```
fillarray(arr, rows, cols);
```

Just like you have so far. Now, you have array arr all filled in. minarray doesn't care how that happened. So don't pass it your filler method. Pass it the array.

```
minarray(cols, arr[z]);
```

You don't need to pass the entire array -- just the row in question. You're also passing the width.

And change the definition of minarray:

```
void minarray(int length, int[] array)
```

Now, your minarray itself needs changes. First, get rid of the if-check. You don't need to pass a row number now, but you do need the number of columns passed as length.

Then your for loop looks like:

```
for (int index = 0; index < length; ++index) {
    if (array[index] < min) {
        min = array[index];
    }
}
```

So, to summarize:

- Main declares the data and calls your two methods.
- fillarray populates the array. It is called from main the way you already have.
- minarray prints the minimum on a single line. It is also called from main, passing in the array, not the method that filled it.

You have one more issue, however. fillarray hardcodes the array size as 5x5, but main uses constants defined. I'd move those contents to the top of the file and use them in both places.

Move to the top, below any #includes:

```
const int rows = 5;
const int cols = 5;
```

Define fillarray:

```
void fillarray(int arr[rows][cols]) {
```

And when you call it from main:

```
fillarray(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll let the other answers answer your question and concentrate on the code around your `goto` that you asked about in the comments.

In `main` you have this:

```
    cout << "Enter the number of row: ";
    cin >> z;
    minarray(z, fillarray)
```

In `minarray` you have this:

```
void minarray(int a, void fillarray) { // don't know what to write here

there:
    int min = INT_MAX; // Value of INT_MAX is 2147483648.

    if(a > 4) {
        cout << "Invalid input! " << endl;
        goto there;
    }
```

First, there's absolutely no reason to use `goto`. You could do this:

```
void minarray(int a, void fillarray) { // don't know what to write here
    int min = INT_MAX; // Value of INT_MAX is 2147483648.

    while(a > 4) { // loop for as long as "a > 4"
        cout << "Invalid input! " << endl;
    }
```

Removing the `goto` made the bug rather apparent. `a` will never change inside the loop, so it'll just print `Invalid input!` forever if you give it invalid input. An alternative would be to validate the input when you actually get the input from the user (in `main`):

```
    while(true) { // loop forever
        cout << "Enter the number of row: ";
        if(cin >> z) {                  // check that the user inputs an int 
            if(z<0 || z>4)              // validate the input
                cout << "Invalid input!\n";
            else
                break;                  // we got valid input, break out of the while loop
        } else {                        // user did not input an int
            std::cout << "input failed - aborting\n";
            return 1;                   // return from main to exit the program
        }
    } // if the program reaches this point, it'll ask the user for input again
      // and that will only happen if the user gives it an int that is <0 or >4
```

Comment: I used goto because at the end of for loop I have this line     

`cout << "Minimum element is " << min << endl;` and it was printig after "Invalid value" error

Comment: @jane What I propose doesn't change the logic of your program. You'll still have your printout at the end of the function. But, you do not _ever_ need `goto` and as you may have noticed, when I removed it and replaced it with a much shorter equivalent - it's easy to see a bug in your code - that I also proposed a fix for.

Comment: Okay, I understood. Thanks for your time and patience)